# ser_open(): cant set com-state for "\\.\COM5" on Arduino Pro Micro

Tags: arduino

Arduino: 1.8.3 (Windows 7), Board: "Arduino Leonardo"

I have checked all that my settings are correct, a different wire, uninstalling and reinstalling Arduino program and the driver.

When I first got it, it worked perfectly but then I tried uploading a sketch that took up 97% of the memory and after that it has stopped working. When I plug it in, the green light goes on immediately and the red light goes on a bit after, both of them are solid.

Here's the error message:

> Sketch uses 3618 bytes (12%) of program storage space. Maximum is 28672 bytes.
>   Global variables use 149 bytes (5%) of dynamic memory, leaving 2411 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 2560 bytes.
>   avrdude: ser_open(): can't set com-state for "\.\COM5"
>   An error occurred while uploading the sketch
>
> This report would have more information with "Show verbose output
>   during compilation" option enabled in File -> Preferences.